# Standalone module for nodejs?

Tags: node.js, module

I would like to create a module for nodejs that can be used standalone. The module source is literally just JavaScript files that are executed using nodejs.

I am not sure exactly how this would work, but essentially:

```
npm install mymodule

node mymodule inputfile

or better

mymodule inputfile
```

How would this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an excellent guide for writing modules on [how to node](http://howtonode.org/how-to-module).

[Jade](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade) is a great example of executable module.